# Jupyter - widget to play audio with playhead on graph

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, jupyter, visualization

Is there any Jupyter widget for visualizing audio synced with a playhead on a time-series plot?

I would like to visualize data derived from an audio sample (e.g. spectrogram and various computed signals), listening to the audio sample while seeing the playhead move across the plots.

I found this old gist https://gist.github.com/deeplycloudy/2152643 which uses pyaudio on the Python backend to play the sound. Any good solutions out there that are a bit less hacky, e.g. ideally entirely JavaScript-based and with playback running fully in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the time since I posted this question, a few new solutions have emerged:

- [Scott Condron: Building Tools to Interact With Your Data](https://www.scottcondron.com/jupyter/visualisation/audio/2020/10/21/interactive-audio-plots-in-jupyter-notebook.html)
- [Building Tools to Interact With Your Data 2020-10-21-interactive-audio-plots-in-jupyter-notebook.ipynb](https://github.com/scottire/fastpages/blob/master/_notebooks/2020-10-21-interactive-audio-plots-in-jupyter-notebook.ipynb)

These solutions use holoview, have a playhead linked between the audio and the plots, and can run fully on the browser.

Answer (score 4):

You can now :).  It took me about 10 minutes to put together a demo using Jupyter proxy widget to load a `wavesurfer` control into a notebook.  It works in Chrome but I haven't tested it anywhere else. It should work anywhere `wavesurfer` and Jupyter work.

Here is a screenshot

[image: notebook screen shot]

See the pastable text from the notebook here:

https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_doodle/blob/master/notebooks/misc/wavesurfer%20demo.ipynb

For information on jp_proxy widgets look here:

https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_proxy_widget

Comment: Very nice... got me wondering now if there are js packages out there that would support visualisations like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEOxKMEfsQc ... Ah ha.. https://wavesurfer-js.org/example/spectrogram/index.html So maybe... just need to think about the chunking of eg 15s fragments...

Comment: Thank you! This is close, but it shows the waveform of the audio directly. What I want to do is to compute various signals of my own from the audio (e.g. a numpy time series of "average beat intensity", 10 samples per second), and have it displayed/scroll in parallel with the audio. The Spectrogram plugin in "scroll" mode is closer! I would want to have my own custom data displayed.

Comment: I've done a quick post and MyBinder demo showing how to use the spectogram plugin with the jp_proxy_widget here: https://blog.ouseful.info/2020/01/11/rapid-widget-prototyping-using-third-party-javascript-packages-in-jupyter-notebooks/

Comment: Does not work in JupyterLab, at least not with what I have installed.  Some notion of dependencies (and since JupyterLab's interactions with widgets is touchy, that may include version numbers of package combinations known to work) is necessary.  Too bad, it looks like a nice tool otherwise.

Comment: most widgets do not work in colab, unfortunately